# Can a browser modified or create extension to give option to save playing videos?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, encryption, streaming

Nowadays, most sites encrypt or use DRM for playing videos. But browser can not play the file directly, it must be decrypted. Whatever the process is, ultimately browser need an actual playable video file.

So, is it possible to modify a browser like chrome to add button over video element to download video which is already decrypted and streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a project called [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) that lets you download a video locally, and you can even specify the format and audio/video quality.
Major browsers have extensions that integrate with this command line application, like [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-dlforextension/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) for example.

Comment: youtube-dl may download video file but will not be able to decrypt it. So, technically the downloaded file is completely useless. And thats the case for only sites which uses adapative stream where video information is available in manifest file. But some sites like instagram keeps video in memory and creates blob object and plays video. In such case its impossible to download even encrypted video.